# Is this a correct first-order formalisation?

Tags: first-order-logic

Statement: $R$ is a set containing only ordered pairs.

Translation: $\forall x(x\in R\rightarrow\exists a\exists b(x=\{\{ a\} ,\{ a,b\}\} )$

Comment: It's correct provided (1) you're working in a context where everything is a set (otherwise, you should say that $R$ is a set) and (2) your vocabulary includes the notations $\{a\}$ and $\{a,b\}$ (otherwise, you should incorporate their definitions into your formula).

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes, I do assume that everything is a set. For your second point, please tell me if I’m correct in what follows. To express $\{ a\}$, I can give it a name $A$ and say that $\exists A\forall x(x\in A\leftrightarrow x=a)\}$. Can I do this?

Comment: The formula that you suggested in your comment expresses "$\{a\}$ exists." For your original problem, you'll need ways to express $u=\{a\}$, $v=\{a,b\}$, and $x=\{u,v\}$.